# Print XML tag names and values in Java

Tags: xml, parsing, tags

I have an XML document, and I want to print the tag names and values (of leaf nodes) of all tags in the document.

For example, for the XML:

```
<library>
  <bookrack>
    <book>
      <name>Book1</name>
      <price>$10</price>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>Book2</name>
      <price>$15</price>
    </book>
  </bookrack>
</library>
```

The output should be something like:

```
library=
bookrack=
book=
name=Book1
price=$10
book=
name=Book2
price=$15
```

Help please!

Comment: Sorry for getting back late.. but I was looking for a solution in Java.. (see question title) :)

Comment: Maybe I should have tagged the question as "java" too.. :)

Comment: Yes, this info would have been valuable to have right from the start. In any case, you can apply XSLT in Java, no problem. *If* you want to to try that road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimalistic XSLT 1.0 approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives:

```
library=
bookrack=
book=
name=Book1
price=$10
book=
name=Book2
price=$15
```

This alternative template would treat the node values better:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(text()) != ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

The output is the same as before, but spacing within node values would be retained.

Answer (score 0):

if you can parse the xml with xslt then it is quite simple (output can be changed to text just used html to be able to view the result easily)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="./*">
         <xsl:call-template name="list" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*" name="list">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)" /> = <xsl:value-of select="text()" /><br />
      <xsl:for-each select="./*">
         <xsl:call-template name="list" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns:

```
library = 
bookrack = 
book = 
name = Book1
price = $10
book = 
name = Book2
price = $15
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Let me see if I can use this instead of a Java program.. :)