# Printing the set of key-value pairs of data inside a XML element using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

For a given XML Node I need to get the key value pairs of it. For an example:

For XML :

```
<root>
    <detail1>
        <test1> Text1 </test1>
        <test2> Text2 </test2>
        <test3> Text3 </test3>
    </detail1>
    <detail2> description 1 </detail2>
    <detail3> description 2 </detail3>
</root>
```

I need a table as follows (Ignoring the top most element) :

```
detail1 | test1 : Text1 
        | test2 : Text2
        | test2 : Text3
        |
detail2 | description 1
        |
detail3 | description 2
```

Is this possible with XSLT? If anyone can point me to a example or a resource it would be very useful.

Comment: What format of table do you want, HTML?

Comment: yes I need a HTML table.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution that is fully in the spirit of XSLT (uses push style). It is the only answer so far that produces exactly the wanted output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vBlanks" select="'                         '"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', name(), ' | ')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' : ')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[not(position()=1)]">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($vBlanks,1,string-length(name(..))+1)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('| ', name(), ' : ')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <detail1>
        <test1> Text1 </test1>
        <test2> Text2 </test2>
        <test3> Text3 </test3>
    </detail1>
    <detail2> description 1 </detail2>
    <detail3> description 2 </detail3>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
detail1 | test1 :  Text1 
        | test2 :  Text2 
        | test3 :  Text3 
detail2 |  description 1 
detail3 |  description 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Print XML tag names and values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097326/print-xml-tag-names-and-values-in-java). The main idea is to name() and text() functions and building the format should be relatively easy

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need the `for-each` tag which allows you to loop over the result of a XPath expression.

See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp for an explanation and a use case.

Answer (score 1):

I like using xsl:apply-templates better than using xsl:for-each.

*Edit: changed match clause from* `*[text()]` *to* `*[count(text()) = 1]`

If you apply this transform

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/*"/>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[count(text()) = 1]">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="keyvalue"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="keyvalue">
    <tr>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="formatkeyvalue"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="formatkeyvalue"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="formatkeyvalue">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' : ', text())"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your input, you get

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>detail1</td>
      <td>test1 :  Text1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test2 :  Text2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>test3 :  Text3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>detail2</td>
      <td> description 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>detail3</td>
      <td> description 2 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But when I run this, the generated table is missing test1, test2, test3 values. I'm very new to xslt. Can you give me a hint what might be the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @sunnyj: weird. I developed the solution with Xselerator and it worked (great tool, by the way). After reading your comment I re-tested the transform in visual studio and it failed just like you described. Interesting, but annoying. I think I found what caused it and updated my answer. Does this one work?

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table border="1px">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),' : ')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>detail1</td>
        <td>test1 :  Text1 
            <br />test2 :  Text2 
            <br />test3 :  Text3 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>detail2</td>
        <td> description 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>detail3</td>
        <td> description 2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```